# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{4t^3+12}{12t^6+3nt+2}dt=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{4t^3+12}{12t^6+3nt+2}dt=0$.

I would like to use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. But, I couldn't see how we can dominate the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ by an integrable function $g$ over $[0,\infty)$ where $f_n(t)=\frac{4t^3+12}{12t^6+3nt+2}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,t\in [0,\infty)$.

Thanks!

Comment: $$
\frac{{4t^3  + 12}}{{12t^6  + 3nt + 2}} \le \frac{{4t^3  + 12}}{{12t^6  + 2}}.
$$ The RHS is $\mathcal{O}(t^{ - 3} )$ at $+\infty$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ at the origin, so is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n$ and $t>0$
$$\frac{4t^3+12}{12t^6+3nt+2}<\max\{\frac{4t^3+12}{2},\frac{4t^3+12}{12t^6}\}$$
and the r.h.s is integrable in $[0,\infty)$, so you can use the Lebesgue's dominated theorem.